# What fields am I supposed to populate in test_configurations.json?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am very new to Azure and cloud services in general. I am trying to experiment with the azure storage sdk (https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-cpp) to use in my application and am trying to get used to it. I'm trying to run the tests to make sure that I built the library correctly.

Looking at the README it says to fill in the `test_configurations.json` file but I don't know what should be filled in or how to obtain the info that should actually be in there. I signed up for the free Azure account and create a storage account but I don't see client_id, tenant_id or client secret anywhere in the console. Here is the config file:

```
{
  "target": "production",
  "premium_target": "premium_account",
  "blob_storage_target": "blob_storage_account",
  "tenants": [
    {
      "name": "devstore",
      "type": "devstore",
      "connection_string": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
    },
    {
      "name": "production",
      "type": "cloud",
      "connection_string": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;"
    },
    {
      "name": "premium_account",
      "type": "cloud",
      "connection_string": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;"
    },
    {
      "name": "blob_storage_account",
      "type": "cloud",
      "connection_string": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;"
    }
  ],
  "token_information": {
    "account_name": "",
    "tenant_id": "",
    "client_id": "",
    "client_secret": "",
    "resource": "https://storage.azure.com"
  }
}
```

How do I obtain the ids and secrets that I need?

Answer (score 0):

You need to register an application as storage client and then you can obtain those details
as mentioned [**`here`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-app?tabs=dotnet#register-your-application-with-an-azure-ad-tenant)

> The first step in using Azure AD to authorize access to storage
> resources is registering your client application with an Azure AD